# How to combine corresponding time entries and their duration into new object?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm wondering how I can accomplish this (partially with Linq, perhaps? A recursive method?). It's utterly confusing me.

Suppose I have a list of Time Tracking objects that looks something like this:

```
Public Class TimeTracker
    Public TimeTrackerID as integer
    Public UserID As Integer
    Public WorkstationID as Integer
    Public WorkDateTime As DateTime
    Public isEntry As Boolean
    Public isExit As Boolean
End Class
```

Ordered by WorkDateTime, UserID, WorkStationID

I want to end up with a list with objects that look like this:

```
Public Class TimeTracker
    Public TimeTrackerID as integer
    Public UserID as integer
    Public WorkstationID as integer
    Public Date as Date
    Public EntryTime as datetime
    Public ExitTime as datetime
    Public Duration as TimeSpan
End Class
```

Basically, WorkDateTime tells us when the timestamp happened and isEntry/isExit tell us whether the employee was coming or going.

I need to loop through the data and make sure the entry/exit times are valid i.e. that for each User in each Workstation for a given date the entry time precedes the exit time and there is a corresponding exit time for each entry time.

If the times are indeed valid, I need to merge the two time entries into one object with Entry/Exit time and the time span between the two.

If the times are not valid, for example there's only an entry time, or only an exit time, or the exit time is before the entry time, then the object should stay as it was, just put into the properties of the new object.

Any help or direction is appreciated.
Sample Data

```
 - TimeTrackerID | UserID | WorkStationID | WorkDateTime     | isEntry | isExit
 -   1           |  1     |   66          | 1/1/2013 8:00 AM | True    | False
 -   2           |  1     |   66          | 1/1/2013 9:00 AM | False   | True
 -   3           |  2     |   77          | 1/1/2013 8:00 AM | True    | False
 -   4           |  2     |   77          | 2/1/2013 9:45 AM | False   | True
...
```

Should turn into

```
 - TimeTrackerID | UserID | WorkStationID | Date     | EntryTime | ExitTime | Duration
 -   1           |  1     |   66          | 1/1/2013 | 8:00 AM   | 9:00 AM  | 1 hour
 -   3           |  2     |   77          | 1/1/2013 | 8:00 AM   | NULL     | NULL
 -   4           |  2     |   77          | 2/1/2013 | NULL      | 9:45 AM  | NULL
...
```

Any help or direction is mightily appreciated.

Comment: If the starting data is in a list you can use the FindAll method with a delegate to find all entries for each UserId this sub list can then be parsed and the new data put into a list of a new class that implements the old one and adds the extra properties.

Comment: Thank you!! This helped me a lot in figuring out what to do. I would have marked you as answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to tinstaafl - what I ended up doing was group my objects by the three grouping criteria (UserID, WorkstationID and Date) and then performing my validation method on each group (to see whether the times matched within the group). I created a class that inherits from the old TimeTracker class with added properties. I used these objects for the groups that contained valid times.